# file_get_contents(): Peer certificate did not match

Tags: php

I used PHP 5.5 but I forced to update it and now I'm using PHP 5.6.19.

Now, when I'm trying to communicate with external API I get warning:

> Warning: file_get_contents(): Peer certificate CN=`*.domain.com' did
>   not match expected CN=`api.domain.com'

It hasn't appeared in previous PHP version.

```
    $encryptedEncodedData // this is json encoded
//array, then encrypted by mcrypt with rijndael-128 and finally bin2hex.

    $context = stream_context_create(array(
                        'http' => array(
                            'method' => 'POST',
                            'header' => 'Content-Type: application/json',
                            'content' => $encryptedEncodedData,
                        )
                    ));

    $api = 'https://api.domain.com/service';

    $response = file_get_contents($api, FALSE, $context);
```

I don't know what is reason for this warning.

---

I decided to disable peer verfy until my admins will fix problem with cert and I changed $context following:

```
$context = stream_context_create(array(
                    'http' => array(
                        'method' => 'POST',
                        'header' => 'Content-Type: application/json',
                        'content' => $encryptedEncodedData,
                        'verify_peer'      => false,
                        'verify_peer_name' => false,
                        ), 
                    )
                );
```

But still not working. Did I do this correct? Getting same Warning.

Comment: Seems to be a problem with the API's SSL certificate.

Comment: From http://php.net/manual/en/context.ssl.php , changes in 5.6+ `verify_peer_name. verify_peer default changed to TRUE` which means that prior to 5.6 there was no peer verification by default?

Comment: What is the endpoint you are trying to reach?

Comment: Start by debugging the remote certificate, e.g. `openssl s_client -connect servername:443` (see [manual](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/apps/s_client.html)), or https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/. What does that give you?

Comment: @deceze `Assessment failed: IP address is from private address space (RFC 1918)` using ssllabs.com/ssltest

Comment: Well, an external service can't debug your intranet. You'll have to use the `openssl` command line tool then.

Comment: Just for knowledge. Can't v use cURL here ?

Comment: @M.S.P API should give me callback with **crypted** and **json encoded** data. Can i do this same with cURL?
@deceze `PS C:\Users\Me> openssl s_client -connect api.domain.com/service:443
WARNING: can't open config file: /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf
Loading 'screen' into random state - done
gethostbyname failure
connect:errno=11001`

Comment: @Bejkrools you url looks invalid ;) `api.domain.com/service:443` port can't be defined there. `api.comain.com:443/services` is valid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There seems to be something wrong with the SSL certificate.

But the settings is changed in php 5.6 you can fix this by ignoring the verification, or when you have a self signed certificate allow_self_signed can be related.

```
 stream_context_create($ourStuff, ['verify_peer' => false]);
```

More information and settings:
http://php.net/manual/en/context.ssl.php

Which is referred to from http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-create.php

Note that disabling validation can be a security risk, and should be only done if you know what you are doing.

The default value of verify_peer has been changed to `true` in newer php versions (>= 5.6). Which means there was always a security risk.

As noted by deceze you should only do this when you are sure all other things are correctly like your own php configuration:

Step 1: test the remote certificate whether it's valid using openssl CLI tool or whatever other methods you prefer. If remote cert is fine.

Step 2: figure out why PHP can't accept it. If it's because PHP has problems validating wildcard certs, see if there's some fix for that. Or if it's because PHP doesn't have a local CA store, which is easy to fix.

Step 3: disable peer verification.

Comment: Disabling peer verification is a bad idea without knowing what exactly it is that goes wrong, whether it can be fixed and whether the implications are clear.

Comment: TL;DR the above is not a fix

Comment: @PeeHaa The above is a backwards compatibility "hack" to reflect changes in the defaults between php 5.6+ and versions prior to this.

Comment: I agree on this, but when the client certificatie is somehow invalid and you don't have control. You can temporarily fix it like this so you scripts are at least running when they are critical/required.

Comment: Introducing a major security vulnerability in a critical script seems like a bad idea, Sander.

Comment: Agreed with @PeeHaa, you should only ever outright disable peer verification **if there's no other way to fix the problem**, and you need to be very aware of the implications. It should *not* be your first go-to solution.

Comment: No I mean you implemented an API from a third party an bam certificates are invalid but you need access to their API. This could be a solution. You can't tell you boss well our company needs to stop for a week until that third party fixes their certificates

Comment: @Sander What's indicating that it's the *3rd party's fault* here? Seems like PHP has problems validating the certificate on its end, the certificate itself may be perfectly fine. Either PHP cannot accept wildcard certificates, or perhaps the local CA store is empty/doesn't contain the signing authority for this cert.

Comment: @deceze from the question "Now, when I'm trying to communicate with external API i get warning:" and the php version upgrade to 5.6.0 and later. before the default was `false`

Comment: Yes, so? PHP's problem, not the 3rd party's.

Comment: Ok, so changing it back to `false` is  a security risk so don't do it. And we can't fix the certificate issues. Now what? close a company until they fixed their certificates? let the server down until php fixes it back to `false` which is never going to happen? downgrade php version could be a option (with the same security risks).

Comment: Step 1: test the remote certificate whether it's valid using `openssl` CLI tool or whatever other methods you prefer. If remote cert is fine, Step 2: figure out why PHP can't accept it. If it's because PHP has problems validating wildcard certs, see if there's some fix for that. Or if it's because PHP doesn't have a local CA store, which is easy to fix. Only if any of these steps are unfixable, Step 3: disable peer verification. – Don't jump there directly.

Comment: I agree on this, but I assumed the client certificate is just invalid. but it could be the case that php is configured wrongly. updated

Comment: @Bejkrools The `verify_peer` option should be passed as the second parameter not mixed with the first parameter or in the ssl section in the first parameter (i think, not sure or tested)

Answer (score 7):

Temporary fixing:

```
$context = stream_context_create(array(
                    'http' => array(
                        'method' => 'POST',
                        'header' => 'Content-Type: application/json',
                        'content' => $encryptedEncodedData,
                        ),
                    'ssl' => array(
                        'verify_peer'      => false,
                        'verify_peer_name' => false,
                        ),
                    )
                );
```

Thanks for everyone

Answer (score 5):

This works for me. The key was setting 'allow_self_signed' to TRUE.

```
    stream_context_set_default(array(
            'ssl'                => array(
            'peer_name'          => 'generic-server',
            'verify_peer'        => FALSE,
            'verify_peer_name'   => FALSE,
            'allow_self_signed'  => TRUE
             )));


    $response = file_get_contents($url, FALSE);
```

Comment: where to set this configuration?

Answer (score 3):

I know this is old, but I just recently in my life had to deal with this issue and found a solution, so I'm posting it through the web to help others:

I had the same problem and spent countless hours looking for an answer. I hope that I can help the community of developers by sharing the solution to the swift_transportexception connection issue. Here it is...

***Make the following adjustment to your .env file:***

```sh
MAIL_DRIVER=sendmail

MAIL_HOST=YOUR_DOMAIN.COM

MAIL_PORT=465

MAIL_USERNAME=YOUR_EMAIL@YOUR_DOMAIN.COM

MAIL_PASSWORD=YOUR_PASSWORD

MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl

MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=YOUR_EMAIL@YOUR_DOMAIN.COM

MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
```

Make sure your DNS records is set to:  MX - @ - mail.YOUR_DOMAIN.COM - Priority 0

Answer (score 1):

having a quite similar problem in php 7.1

looks like a bug for me:

https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=76196

calling `file_get_contents` through a configured proxy to an ssl site will let the certificate check "lag" one behind.

with the first call of the `file_get_contents` the certificate for the requested site will be "locked in" for the next call. which will therefor fail.

so only the first call of `file_get_contents` will be successful, the rest will fail.

```
<?php
$stream_default_opts = [
  'http' => [
    'proxy'=>"tcp://5.9.78.28:3128",
    'request_fulluri' => true,
  ]
];
stream_context_set_default($stream_default_opts);
file_get_contents("https://www.symfony.com", false); 
file_get_contents("https://getcomposer.org", false); 
file_get_contents("https://github.com", false);
```

Actual result:

```
Warning: file_get_contents(): Peer certificate CN=`getcomposer.org' did not match expected CN=`www.symfony.com' in foo.php on line 11
Warning: file_get_contents(https://getcomposer.org): failed to open stream: Cannot connect to HTTPS server through proxy in foo.php on line 11

Warning: file_get_contents(): Peer certificate CN=`github.com' did not match expected CN=`www.symfony.com' in foo.php on line 12
Warning: file_get_contents(https://github.com): failed to open stream: Cannot connect to HTTPS server through proxy in foo.php on line 12
```

Answer (score 0):

If you worry about security, use curl instead of file_get_contents.

```
$url = "https://www.google.com/"
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/31.0.1650.63 Safari/537.36');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

This function is the same as file get contents but not require you turn of security mode