# Connection could not be established with host smtp.mailtrap.io :stream_socket_client(): when using SENDGRID to send mail

Tags: php, laravel, email, laravel-5, sendgrid

I am using send grid mail to send mail in Laravel but when i try to send the email i get following error :

> "message": "Connection could not be established with host
>   smtp.mailtrap.io :stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to
>   smtp.mailtrap.io:2525 (Connection refused)",
>       "exception": "Swift_TransportException",
>
> env file:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.sendgrid.net
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=XXXX
MAIL_PASSWORD=XXXX
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS = XXXX
MAIL_FROM_NAME = XXXXX
```

> Mail.php

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Mail Driver
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Laravel supports both SMTP and PHP's "mail" function as drivers for the
    | sending of e-mail. You may specify which one you're using throughout
    | your application here. By default, Laravel is setup for SMTP mail.
    |
    | Supported: "smtp", "sendmail", "mailgun", "mandrill", "ses",
    |            "sparkpost", "postmark", "log", "array"
    |
    */

    'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | SMTP Host Address
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may provide the host address of the SMTP server used by your
    | applications. A default option is provided that is compatible with
    | the Mailgun mail service which will provide reliable deliveries.
    |
    */

    'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailgun.org'), 

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | SMTP Host Port
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This is the SMTP port used by your application to deliver e-mails to
    | users of the application. Like the host we have set this value to
    | stay compatible with the Mailgun e-mail application by default.
    |
    */

    'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Global "From" Address
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | You may wish for all e-mails sent by your application to be sent from
    | the same address. Here, you may specify a name and address that is
    | used globally for all e-mails that are sent by your application.
    |
    */




    'from' => [
        'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS'),
        'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME'),
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | E-Mail Encryption Protocol
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify the encryption protocol that should be used when
    | the application send e-mail messages. A sensible default using the
    | transport layer security protocol should provide great security.
    |
    */

    'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | SMTP Server Username
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | If your SMTP server requires a username for authentication, you should
    | set it here. This will get used to authenticate with your server on
    | connection. You may also set the "password" value below this one.
    |
    */

    'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),

    'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Sendmail System Path
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When using the "sendmail" driver to send e-mails, we will need to know
    | the path to where Sendmail lives on this server. A default path has
    | been provided here, which will work well on most of your systems.
    |
    */

    'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Markdown Mail Settings
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | If you are using Markdown based email rendering, you may configure your
    | theme and component paths here, allowing you to customize the design
    | of the emails. Or, you may simply stick with the Laravel defaults!
    |
    */

    'markdown' => [
        'theme' => 'default',

        'paths' => [
            resource_path('views/vendor/mail'),
        ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Log Channel
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | If you are using the "log" driver, you may specify the logging channel
    | if you prefer to keep mail messages separate from other log entries
    | for simpler reading. Otherwise, the default channel will be used.
    |
    */

    'log_channel' => env('MAIL_LOG_CHANNEL'),

];
```

I have run following commands also but the same issue :

```
php artisan config:clear 
php artisan cache:clear
```

Please help to solve out my issue.

Comment: Error shows that you are trying to connect to smtp.mailtrap.io, check your mail.php config

Comment: @Yurich : should i change this value : 'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailgun.org') in mail.php, i have set  MAIL_HOST=smtp.sendgrid.net in env file

Comment: Looks OK. Check mail config that Laravel is using. In code or in tinker run config('mail');

Comment: should i change 'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailgun.org'),  to 'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.sendgrid.net'),

Comment: Wherewer, it must take value from env, env('ENV_VALUE', 'default_value_when_no_env')

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and spent countless hours looking for an answer. I hope that I can help the community of developers by sharing the solution to the swift_transportexception connection issue. Here it is...

***Make the following adjustment to your .env file:***

```sh
MAIL_DRIVER=sendmail

MAIL_HOST=YOUR_DOMAIN.COM

MAIL_PORT=465

MAIL_USERNAME=YOUR_EMAIL@YOUR_DOMAIN.COM

MAIL_PASSWORD=YOUR_PASSWORD

MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl

MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=YOUR_EMAIL@YOUR_DOMAIN.COM

MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
```

Make sure your DNS records is set to:  MX - @ - mail.YOUR_DOMAIN.COM - Priority 0

Comment: Please don't add [the same answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63367028/1324) to multiple questions. Answer the best one and flag the rest as duplicates. See [Is it acceptable to add a duplicate answer to several questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/104227/347985)

Answer (score -2):

/** change the MAIL_ECRYPTION TO ssl instead of tls **/
Click [here] for more contributions (https://www.171mails.com/?gclid=CjwKCAiA2fmdBhBpEiwA4CcHzeXXnaInit-5_XLuuq_BSqfR4lwmi9pl9gkpkpBryvDYXJSNJB-w_xoCN-QQAvD_BwE)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).