# Can't send emails from laravel project through smtp

Tags: php, laravel, email, smtpclient

These are the settings in my env file

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mail.codestudio.pk
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=hamza.niazi@codestudio.pk
MAIL_PASSWORD=**********
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
```

When I test on mailtrap.io it works fine also works fine with my gmail account. But whenever I try to send mail through my domain it gives this error.

```
Connection could not be established with host mail.codestudio.pk :stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to tcp://mail.codestudio.pk:465 (A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
```

Comment: Hope this link can help you to get your answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61268418/connection-could-not-be-established-with-host-smtp-mailtrap-io-stream-socket-cl

Answer (score 0):

I hope this env works for you. I used the same setting to run it on my server

```
#MAIL_MAILER=smtp
#MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
#MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_HOST=codestudio.pk
MAIL_USERNAME=hamza.niazi@codestudio.pk
MAIL_PASSWORD=**********
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=hamza.niazi@codestudio.pk
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
```

Comment: @HamzaKhan Do you get same error even after this?